# How to post diacritic (or esp swedish) signs to user status through facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

EDIT: For the internet: **utf8_encode** did the trick. At the time of writing this I can't remember if I did urlencode(utf8_encode($msg)) or if utf8_encode($msg) sufficed. However the utf8_encode was needed. Gl hf!

Original question:

I have succeeded in posting status messages to users' statuses through the graph API when the message is (so to speak) content from the normal ascii range.

Like this (PHP):

```
$msg = "Hello dudes!";
$curlobject = new cURL();
$postparams = "access_token=" . SSN_code() . "&message=" . urlencode($msg);
$r = $curlobject->post("https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed",$postparams);
```

-> OK! Status updated as wanted.

However, when I use å, ä or ö in my messages (which I'd like to be able to do, since some users will be Swedish, the status messages display a question mark in a triangle where the diacritic signs are. So, like,

```
$msg = "Hello kåldolmar!";
```

would result in a status of "Hello k�ldolmar!".

Anyone knows how to encode the signs or to complement the graph request with more info to make the messag edisplay correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Use **[htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)**

```
$msg = htmlspecialchars("Hello kåldolmar!");

output will be Hello kåldolmar!
```

Comment: Hi! Sorry for being the slowest being on Earth feedbacking your answer. I went on a trip abroad and this problem got sorted into the backlog for a while.

Unfortunately, htmlspecialchars did not solve the problem. However, utf8_encode did (I'll edit my question in a few secs...). Thank you for your answer anyhow. It will come in handy when printing the HTML pages.